# Kernel panic on Dell R710 Kernel 4.4.1

Tags: debian, dell-poweredge, kernel

We are running Debian 7.9 server with kernel 4.4.1 on Dell R710 (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz) and after some time (maybe once a month) server stop working and I see on a screen the kernel panic.
Can anyone advise me what can cause it, please? Everything happens without our intervention.

not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt

[image: kernel panic]

Comment: Hopefully for you something was indeed changed which would mean you could boot with a rescue disk or USB key and update the kernel.  Otherwise it is likely due to a hardware failure.  Try booting from another drive to see if it works.

Comment: Without the full panic, there's no hope of being able to diagnose this problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that if I reboot the server, it runs again without a problem, but after a few weeks, I get the same kernel panic. It's very strange. Anyway, I will try to change the kernel.

Comment: Also, how can I get the full panic? Only with kdump? Thank you.

Comment: Its more likely to be a firmware/driver problem than a kernel issue. Please add the output of `lsmod` and `cat /proc/interrupts`

Comment: lsmod is empty, no modules 
[cat /proc/interrupts](https://jiri.pokorni.net/inter.txt)

Comment: Does it only happen when you choose to restart it instead of freshly booting it?  Does it crash before this happens?

Comment: It only happens when the system is running fine without any interaction from our side. It's very random behavior. Usually, I reboot the server to fix it. But I know that it's not a solution ..  I'm waiting for results of diagnostic of the server.